# Lagrange question with confusing variables

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x, y) = x^2− xy + y^2$ inside the quarter circle given by $x^2+ y^2\le 1$, constraint  $x, y\ge0$.

I set out the equations
$$
2x-y=2 \lambda x + 2 \lambda y, \quad
2y-x = 2 \lambda x + 2 \lambda y
\quad \text{and} \quad 
x^2+y^2\le1.$$

However I cannot cancel out the variables to find $\lambda$. How am I meant to approach this question?

Comment: Unless specifically told to use Lagrange, I prefer old school “no square is negative” approach. $x^{2}-xy+y^{2}=\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}+(x-y)^{2})$ which is minimum $0$ and maximum $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if you have questions. Kindly feel free to follow this for getting more ideas about this topic.

https://mast.queensu.ca/~math121/Assignments/Unit23_solutions.pdf